# What's wrong with implementing a class?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning Typescript, and on [the Typescript cheat sheet for Classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/static/TypeScript%20Classes-83cc6f8e42ba2002d5e2c04221fa78f9.png), I see:

> ### Type and value
>
> Surprise, a class can be used as both a type and a value:
>
> ```
> const a: Bag = new Bag();
> //       ^-Type    ^-Value
> ```
>
> So, be careful to not do this:
>
> ```
> class C implements Bag {}
> ```

But I don't see what's wrong with a class `C` implementing a type `Bag`. Is the problem that a class can only implement an interface, and `Bag` is assumed to be a class here? The [docs on `implements`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) only mention `interface`s, so that seems to be the case.

If that's the case, then what about what I see in the next column of the cheat sheet?

> ## Common Syntax
>
> ```
> class User extends Account implements Updatable, Serializable {
> //                                    ^- Ensures that the class 
> //                                       conforms to a set of 
> //                                       interfaces or types                                      
> ...
> ```

(The comment is specifically pointing to the `implements` types (`Updatable` and `Serializable`), and not the the `extends` type (`Account`).)

If a class can only implement an interface, then why does this comment mention "interfaces or types"? Shouldn't it just say "Ensures that the class conforms to a set of interfaces"? Combined with the previous vagueness, this apparent contradiction with the docs is confusing me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with all relevant code [as text and not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: @jcalz Hi, the question relates to documentation, so I don't think that there is a minimal reproducible example. As far as text and images go, I spent not a small amount of time including the relevant code listings from the cheat sheet about which I'm talking. So I'm not really sure what I could have done better.

Comment: Do I need to look at that image in order to understand what `Bag` is?  If so, then it should be here as plain text.  If not, then what is `Bag`?

Comment: As a side note, as a newbie to Typescript, the comment asking me to provide things that don't even seem possible and to include text which I think I've already included make me feel unwelcome, like I don't belong in this community. I am unclear if my question is really deficient or if you didn't read it thoroughly. I'd appreciate your helping me to understand.

Comment: interfaces are about the `public` api, but this can force you into implementing not only `private` members, but also really `#hidden` ones. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYHNoG8BQ1oAcBOBLAbmAC4Cm0pER0AvNAEQVF0Dc60AxABa4AmPJAOxr1ufQS1QBfVKlCQYAYWi4AtphAkVgojHhI0GHAWJlGwhiUoSMXXvyG06o+xMlA  And it's still not satisfied.

Comment: I think I included all the relevant details. The relevant detail is that `Bag` is a class. If there are additional details that are relevant, it may require an expert opinion to notice and explain that. I posted this question in order to obtain such an expert opinion. Given that I am pointing out confusion resulting from a 'cheat sheet' provided by Typescript language documentation itself, I don't think it's burdensome to expect that an expert may look at that documentation.

Comment: Thank you, @Thomas. I am confused about why the disclaimer "be careful to not do this" appears under the heading "Type and value". Based upon your observation, it appears that this has more to do with trying to implement a class that has private members. And based upon the behavior that Typescript returns errors when a user tries to do this, I am not sure that it was necessary to include this disclaimer in a cheat sheet. Maybe the cheat sheet was written before the Typescript compiler returned errors for this situation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not just meant to benefit those asking the questions, but also to future users with the same or similar questions.  Some of those people might not be sighted, and images of text do not help them. I don't really understand why you don't want to copy the definition of `Bag` into your question. I would have been happy to do this for you, but at this point it feels like it might not be productive to continue interacting. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz. Your point about accessibility is a good one. I have included a code listing from Thomas below for the benefit of all. I would like to underscore, though, that you implied that I was 'unable or unwilling' to copy the code over, but my intention was only to include the relevant details, and I lacked your expertise to see how other details on the cheat sheet were relevant. I think that if you were able to see Typescript typing with beginner's eyes, you would better understand that how I phrased my question was because I didn't have your expert perspective.

Comment: I see now how I could have provided a minimal example ([here is one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYHNoG8C+AodpIwMLQEsBbABxAFMjyA7AFxniTSA)), but I don't think it would have added much to my question since it would have contained the same misunderstanding as my question.

Comment: I have edited the question title to help others who see it to better choose whether to look at it.

Comment: Given `class Bag {}` and `class C implements Bag {}`, I'd say the reason why the latter might be a mistake is that `class D extends Bag {}` behaves differently.  Both of them are valid TS code but they do different things.  `class C implements Bag{}` says that `C` will structurally match `Bag`, but `class D extends Bag{}` actually inherits from `Bag` at runtime.  So `new C() instanceof Bag` is `false` while `new D() instanceof Bag` is `true`.  The differences between them can get larger depending on what `Bag` is.  People rarely intend for one class to "implement" another.

Comment: My guess is that the cheat sheet is warning you not to accidentally implement a class when you meant to extend it, but I don't know for sure, since I didn't write that.

Comment: @CarlG I don't know the motivation behind that statement; I didn't write it. These are just the red flags that came to my mind.

Comment: Thank you jcalz and Thomas for your responses. They have been super helpful. (I didn't intend to direct the question of 'what was the author thinking' to either of you. I was just musing publicly on my thought process. And who knows, maybe someone who maintains the cheat sheet will come across this thread and address the confusion somehow.) Thanks again very much.

Comment: @jcalz, I recognize that this comment thread has gotten very long, but since you are a highly active user on new posts, and SO is trying to deal with its reputation as being unwelcoming, I find it important to point out that my original question, as written, contained all of the relevant code necessary to explain my question and to receive a thorough answer. I realize that it must be tedious for you to deal with newbie questions like mine, but suggesting that I was unwilling or unable to provide an acceptable question was just not correct, and I found it unfriendly.

Comment: Ack, @jcalz. Thank you for trying to explain yourself. And as for my explanation, I took time, in my initial answer, to transcribe all of the relevant code from the cheat sheet. If I had transcribed additional code, I would have ended up including extraneous details about private members. If I had added `class Bag {}` (which is the only thing my question could be said to have been missing) then I would have been adding my own interpretation of what the authors had meant, which might have been incorrect.

Comment: I believe that a sight-impaired person would be able to fully understand my question as written and that the text as written is sufficient. What is problematic about your comments is your ongoing implication that the question must be edited to conform with SO's policies. Since that is not the case, I believe that your attitude will be off-putting to new SO users.

Comment: Okay, sorry @jcalz. I am not trying to badger you. I am trying to provide feedback. I think I just don't understand what was wrong with my question, but I respect that you have a different opinion that it could be improved. If you could maybe be more specific in the future, it might help. "Please provide a link to a code playground site to make the code example more clear" or "Please add `class Bag {}` to your question, since it is required to make the code example complete." Otherwise I felt that I was being told that my question was deficient in some way, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between "values" and "types" is that values exist at runtime, while types do not. Surprisingly for newcomers to the language, a class is both a value and a type: a value, because it describes a prototype object that will exist at runtime, and a type, because typescript can use its shape for type checking.

This means that the identifier `Bar` can mean a value or a type, depending on the context in which it is used. If we write:

```
class C extends Bar {
```

`Bar` refers to a value, because an extends clause expects a value, setting up a prototype inheritance between `C` and `Bar` that causes `C` to inherit all properties of `Bar` at runtime.

However, if we write:

```
class C implements Bar {
```

`Bar` refers to a type, because an implements clause expects a type, expressing that `C` has the same properties as `Bar` in the type system, but not setting up inheritance between the prototype objects of `C` and `Bar`.

For instance, if Bar declares a function:

```
class Bar {
  sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello from Bar");
  }
}
```

the code

```
new C().sayHello();
```

would compile, but throw an exception at runtime because the property `C.sayHello` contains `undefined`, and you can't invoke `undefined`.

That why it's usually a mistake to write `class C implements Bar` if `Bar` refers to a class, because we most likely want runtime inheritance as well.

> if a class can only implement an interface, then why does this comment mention "interfaces or types"? Shouldn't it just say "Ensures that the class conforms to a set of interfaces"? Combined with the previous vagueness, this apparent contradiction with the docs is confusing me.

First, there is no contradiction. We are allowed to write `implements Bar`, even though it may not do what we want.

And the main reason they mention types here is that not all types are interfaces. For instance, you can implement an intersection type:

```
interface Employee {
    name: string;
    salary: number;
}

interface Student {
    name: string;
    gradeAverage: number;
}

type Intern = Employee & Student;

class John implements Intern {
    name = "John Doe";
    salary = 60000;
    gradeAverage = 3.9;
}
```

> why the cheat sheet authors found it necessary to include a disclaimer about an edge-case that the Typescript compiler itself will catch

Probably because it helps with understanding the error message, and because the compiler can not catch all cases. For instance, if you do:

```
class Marker {
  // no members, used for instanceof only
}

class C implements Marker {
}
```

will compile just fine, but `new C() instanceof Marker` will return `false`.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful! One question: how could I end up in a situation (using just Typescript) where `new C().sayHello();` would compile but throw a runtime exception? Wouldn't I get a compile-time error at the definition of `class C` that `C` does not implement `Bar` [mre](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0EsC2AHEBTJ6B2AXGAQmAE7QDeAvgFBWiSEnlXTQRgCeAEuiCAPYAKAJRMWLYH2wQ+GAHT8A5gIBE3Xn2gAzYnyTQixZUIDczaNWpVs6AO5xhstlx79hx6FSA)?

Comment: For instance, if `C` is compiled before the property is added to `Bar`, which may happen if `C` and `Bar` are declared in separate npm packages. Then, the compiler seeing `new C().sayHello()` will trust that the compiler of class C has verified the presence of the property, but that compiler didn't do so, because the property hasn't existed yet, and the user, thinking that the property is inherited, might not think to recompile `C` when updating the dependency that contains the `Bar`.

Comment: But you're correct that the compiler will usually catch this, and often suggest an appropriate remedy in the error message. However, there are cases it won't catch, and [cases it will catch, but with a rather mystifying error message](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYCdoG8BQ0PQHZgLYFMB+aAXmgCJ4FyBuVAX1VEhgGFoBLXABxHwKwAXGFRSoG44AHssEKXwB0IKQHMAFFnwB3aKzUBKBTgL6aQA).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I don't think this is the correct answer.

I was not aware that this example and disclaimer, which appeared under the heading "Type and value" related to the previous sections about private members.

If you try to implement a class having private members (typed private or implemented as private), Typescript will return an error:

```
class Bag {
  private test = "test";
  #hidden = "hidden";
}

class C implements Bag {
//    ^- Class 'C' incorrectly implements class 'Bag'. Did you mean to extend 
//       'Bag' and inherit its members as a subclass?
//       Property '#hidden' in type 'C' refers to a different member that
//       cannot be accessed from within type 'Bag'.(2720)
  private test = "test";
  #hidden = "hidden";
}
```

(Although this does raise the question of why the cheat sheet authors found it necessary to include a disclaimer about an edge-case that the Typescript compiler itself will catch. Maybe they wrote the cheat sheet before that error was implemented.)